# How can I find SQL server instances over a network

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

How can I find all the SQL servers installed in our network that were not installed by a DBA? Meaning, someone else has installed the SQL server and we need to get the details like SQL server version, instance name and port number so it can be added to our monitoring scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a network scanning tool that has the ability to fingerprint a node based on the ports that are open and the responses that the node gives back on those ports. Something like [nmap](http://nmap.org/) or the [Microsoft Assessment and Planning (MAP) Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd537566.aspx). Plenty of other network scanning tools exist that can detect what services are running on nodes. From there you can evaluate if the servers that are discovered to be running SQL Server are in your inventory or not.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning all the systems SQL ERRORLOG file is one way to get all the details, without needing to auth to SQL itself.

Log file monitors can do this. You can do log file monitors on the OS, or within SQL Server itself.